# html video mp4 not supported/invalid file path internet explorer

Tags: html, video

for some reason my website doesn't want to play mp4 videos, giving the error: "non-supported video type or invalid file path" (or something symilar like that, translating form dutch). but when I try to watch the same video in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/embedded/result,js,html,css/), it works fine, is there something I'm missing in my video player?

```
<video controls autoplay class="fullsize hide" id='videoThing'>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="videos/Reduce Co2 Of Transport-24.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: These picky browsers... but if you add a  `src="path/to/video.mp4"` to the `<source>`, the video will definitely play.

Comment: @mch I'm appending the src with js, forgot to add it to the source in the little snippet... added it now

Comment: And if you remove/replace the blanks in the filename? The code syntax is ok. Some URL parsers can cope with blanks, but strictly spoken a blank marks the end of a URL.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you have alternative File formats in the source? See any online article about the `video` tag. The syntax is fine, so the problem is in the filename, file format, or the video encoding. It's a pretty deep topic so better read up.

Comment: @mch it's not the encoding, since it works elsewere, I've read many papers on the mp4 format in html, h264 should be supported, could be the dash?

Comment: @mch nope, it's not the dash

Comment: also, `video.canPlayType` returns a true